# Admob not showing ads on debug mode after delaying the app measurement

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have a flutter app in which I have changed how Admob works by delaying the measurement initialization in AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT"
            android:value="true" />
```

But now I can't get ads while executing the app in debug mode:

```
I/Ads     (21615): This request is sent from a test device.
W/Ads     (21615): Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/Ads     (21615): Ad failed to load : 1
```

I have the test ads correctly configured in the AdMob console. If I configure manually in the app my test device the `Ad failed to load : 1` still happens.

The ads are shown correctly in release mode, what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Enable Test Ads https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#sample_ad_units

Comment: Sorry @VIISHRUTMAVANII, I forgot to explain that I have already the test ads enabled. The error is still there, so this is not the cause. I have edited the question to clarify this.